# scipy.sparse.kron matrix not callable

Tags: numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to compute for the triple kronecker product of a matrix given by
T = I⊗I⊗D + I⊗D⊗I + D⊗I⊗I,
with I being the identity matrix and D is just a tridiagonal matrix. So I coded it this way:

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigsh
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs
from scipy import sparse 

# Setting the D matrix
diagonal = -2*np.ones([N])
off_diagonal = np.ones([N])
tridiagonal = np.array([off_diagonal, diagonal, off_diagonal])
D = sparse.spdiags(tridiagonal, np.array([-1, 0, 1]), N, N)
I = np.diag(np.ones([N]))

# Setting the kinetic matrix T
T_1 = sp.sparse(sp.sparse.kron(I, I), D)
T_2 = sp.sparse(sp.sparse.kron(I, D), I)
T_3 = sp.sparse(sp.sparse.kron(D, I), I)
T = T_1 + T_2 + T_3
```

but it returns this error message `'module' object is not callable`. I even wrote it this way

```
A = sparse.kron(I, I)
B = sparse.kron(I, D)
C = sparse.kron(D, I)
T_1 = sparse(A, D)
T_2 = sparse(B, I)
T_3 = sparse(C, I)
T = T_1 + T_2 + T_3
```

but it still returns the same message that

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-29d357553751> in <module>
      7 
      8 # Setting the kinetic matrix T
----> 9 T_1 = sp.sparse(sp.sparse.kron(I, I), D)
     10 T_2 = sp.sparse(sp.sparse.kron(I, D), I)
     11 T_3 = sp.sparse(sp.sparse.kron(D, I), I)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable```
````

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I have made it like this now: ```sp.sparse.kron```, it still returns the same message. Check the post for the message.

Answer (score 2):

I did forget to write .kron. The updated code is here:

```
diagonal = -2*np.ones([N])
off_diagonal = np.ones([N])
tridiagonal = np.array([off_diagonal, diagonal, off_diagonal])
D = sp.sparse.spdiags(tridiagonal, np.array([-1, 0, 1]), N, N)
I = np.diag(np.ones([N]))

# Setting the kinetic matrix T
T_1 = sp.sparse.kron(sp.sparse.kron(I, I), D)
T_2 = sp.sparse.kron(sp.sparse.kron(I, D), I)
T_3 = sp.sparse.kron(sp.sparse.kron(D, I), I)
T = T_1 + T_2 + T_3
```